# 2 counter variables in for loop are not working for equal to condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem Description:

> Given an array arr[] of size N and two elements x and y, use counter
> variables to find which element appears most in the array, x or y. If
> both elements have the same frequency, then return the smaller
> element.
>
> Note:  We need to return the element, not its count.

My solution:

```
def MajorityWins(arr, n, x, y):
    countX = 0
    countY = 0
    for i in arr:
        if i==x:
            countX+=1
        if i==y:
            countY+=1
        if countX>countY:
            return x
        if countY>countX:
            return y
        if countX==countY:
            if x>y:
                return x
            else:
                return y


n=11
arr=[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5]
x=4
y=5

print(MajorityWins(arr, n, x, y))
```

The correct output is 4.

But the output of my program is 5.

When I don't use the condition `countX==countY`, the outputs are correct.

When I add `if countX==countY`, all the other conditions are ignored.

Can someone tell me the solution to this please?

Comment: Your function will return on the first iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Sayse said was absolutely correct. You need to flip the `>` around. But another problem you have it you return while iterating through your list. This can cause problems later on, so please indent it backward so it no on the same indentation level as your loop.

```
    for i in arr:
        if i==x:
            countX+=1
        if i==y:
            countY+=1
    if countX>countY:
        return x
    if countY>countX:
        return y
    if countX==countY:
        if x<y:
            return x
        else:
            return y
```

Answer (score 0):

> If both elements have the same frequency, then return the smaller element.

Your code does the exact opposite of this. If x is greater than y, then you need to return y and vice versa

```
    if countX==countY:
        if x>y:
            return y
        else:
            return x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a print statement in the loop and you will see what is happening. At the end of the loop `countX` has a value of 4, `countY` has a value of 1. 4 is larger than 1 so the value of `x` is returned.

```
def MajorityWins(arr, n, x, y):
    countX = 0
    countY = 0
    for i in arr:
        if i==x:
            countX+=1
        if i==y:
            countY+=1
        print(i, countX, countY)
    if countX>countY:
        result = x
    elif countY>countX:
        result = y
    elif countX==countY:
        if x<y:
            result = x
        else:
            result = y
    return result

n=11
arr=[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5]
x=4
y=5

print(f"Result: {MajorityWins(arr, n, x, y)}")
```

Output:

```
1 0 0
2 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
3 0 0
4 1 0
4 2 0
4 3 0
4 4 0
5 4 1
Result: 4
```